# Remove last part of String in Javascripts

Tags: javascript, string

I'm struggling with a code in JS in order to extract the last part of a String.

Examples of the input strings could be:

```
Event.DEAudience-90c92fe9-7fc8-f7ad-9b10-7eb778f6a857.id
```

or

```
Event.DEAudience-90c92fe9-9b10-7fc8-9b10-7eb778f68888.NNNNNNNN
```

and I need the first part until the second . like this

```
Event.DEAudience-90c92fe9-7fc8-f7ad-9b10-7eb778f6a857
```

or

```
Event.DEAudience-90c92fe9-9b10-7fc8-9b10-7eb778f68888
```

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: Are the two parts always separated by a dot (`.`) and this is the only one in original string?

Comment: have you tried the ```substring()``` function? [look here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

Comment: You can try `your_string.split(".").slice(0, -1).join(".")`. *Note: this may not be the easiest method, but works*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use combination of [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) & [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to do this

```js
var arr = ["Event.DEAudience-90c92fe9-7fc8-f7ad-9b10-7eb778f6a857.id", "Event.DEAudience-90c92fe9-9b10-7fc8-9b10-7eb778f68888.NNNNNNNN"];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  console.log(arr[i].split(".").slice(0, -1).join("."))
}
```

**Working**

`split(".")` returns an array

```js
["Event", "DEAudience-90c92fe9-9b10-7fc8-9b10-7eb778f68888", "NNNNNNNN"]
```

You only need elements up to second last element from this array. For that we can use slice method `slice(0, -1)`, here we are passing range of elements to select. `0` denotes the start index and `-1` (negative indexing) end index denotes last element. Slicing method return elements in the array from start index up to end index (not inclusive). So we'll get,

```js
["Event", "DEAudience-90c92fe9-9b10-7fc8-9b10-7eb778f68888"]
```

Now we need to convert this back to string along with the dots. For that we can use `join(".")` method. It will join elements in the array with `"."` and return as a string

```js
Event.DEAudience-90c92fe9-9b10-7fc8-9b10-7eb778f68888
```

Answer (score 0):

[`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the string into an array on the `.`, and then [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) off the elements up to the last element, and then [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) that array back into a string.

```js
const str = 'Event.DEAudience-90c92fe9-7fc8-f7ad-9b10-7eb778f6a857.id';
const str2 = 'Event.DEAudience-90c92fe9-9b10-7fc8-9b10-7eb778f68888.NNNNNNNN';

function getText(str) {
  const arr = str.split('.');
  return arr.slice(0, arr.length - 1).join('');
}

console.log(getText(str));
console.log(getText(str2));
```